# vba to automatically email select sheet in spreadsheet if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying out a couple different ways to automatically email using VBA and having trouble with the 2 items listed below. The VB does run as is but I would like to try to incorporate these two items if possible. Thank you :).

1. only attach sheet2(attachment). The file is located in bold in the code below.
2. only send the attachment if comment 2 is checked (cell D2)

VB

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim WS As Worksheet, Rng As Range, c As Range
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim Msg As String, Addr As String, FName As String, i As Long
Dim obj As Object
Dim MyFile As String

**MyFile = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form.xlsm"**

    If Dir(MyFile) = "" Then
        MsgBox "The file to attach was not found here:" & vbLf & vbLf & MyFile, vbExclamation, "Exiting"
        GoTo Abort
    End If

On Error Resume Next
Set obj = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If obj Is Nothing Then
    Set obj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
Set Rng = WS.Range("A2", WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each c In Rng
    Msg = Msg & "For " & c.Offset(, 1) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)
    For i = 3 To 14
        If WS.Cells(c.Row, i) = "x" Then
        Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
        End If
    Next
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
    .To = c.Offset(, 0)
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Daily Operational Safety Briefing"
    .Body = Msg
    .Attachments.Add MyFile, 1
    .Send
    End With

    MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation
 Next c

Set OutMail = Nothing

Abort: Application.Quit

Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Update**

```
 Dim MyFile As String, MyFileCopy As String

 MyFileCopy = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Sheet2.xlsm"

 ' no need to look for MyFile because you are working within it ...
 'MyFile = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form.xlsm"
 '    If Dir(MyFile) = "" Then
 '
 '        MsgBox "The file to attach was not found here:" & vbLf & vbLf & MyFile, vbExclamation, "Exiting"
 '        GoTo Abort
 '
 '    End If

'create a separate sheet2 to mail out
Sheets(2).Copy
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
With wkb
    .SaveAs MyFileCopy
    .Close True
End With

'this is not needed, since you set the outlook app below
'    On Error Resume Next
'    Set obj = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
'    On Error GoTo 0
'    If obj Is Nothing Then
'        Set obj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'    End If

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
Set Rng = WS.Range("A2", WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each c In Rng

    If c.Offset(, 3) = "x" Then 'Not sure how you have Comment2 "checked" in column D

        Msg = Msg & "For " & c.Offset(, 1) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)
        For i = 3 To 14
            If WS.Cells(c.Row, i) = "x" Then
                Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
            End If
        Next

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = c.Offset(, 0)
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Daily Operational Safety Briefing"
            .Body = Msg
            .Attachments.Add MyFileCopy, 1
            .Send
        End With


    End If

Next c

MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Abort:

Application.Quit 'This will kill the Excel application, is this really what you want?


End Sub
```

Comment: You have that entire section of code but can't add an If statement?

Comment: I have tried and can not seem to add it in the correct place or get the syntax correct for both.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code. I placed a section to make a copy workbook with sheet2 to send as an attachment as well as added in the condition for D2 (assume column for each row) to check for the condition. See my comments, as I took some liberties without knowing how your exact data works. I also cleaned up some of the stuff that looked superfluous.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim WS As Worksheet, Rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim Msg As String, Addr As String, FName As String, i As Long
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim MyFile As String, MyFileCopy As String

    MyFileCopy = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Attachment.xlsm"

    ' no need to look for MyFile because you are working within it ...
    'MyFile = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form.xlsm"
'    If Dir(MyFile) = "" Then
'
'        MsgBox "The file to attach was not found here:" & vbLf & vbLf & MyFile, vbExclamation, "Exiting"
'        GoTo Abort
'
'    End If

    'create a separate sheet2 to mail out
    Sheets(2).Copy
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wkb
        .SaveAs MyFileCopy
        .Close True
    End With

    'this is not needed, since you set the outlook app below
'    On Error Resume Next
'    Set obj = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
'    On Error GoTo 0
'    If obj Is Nothing Then
'        Set obj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'    End If

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
    Set Rng = WS.Range("A2", WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each c In Rng

        If c.Offset(, 3) = "Checked" Then 'Not sure how you have Comment2 "checked" in column D

            Msg = Msg & "For " & c.Offset(, 1) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)
            For i = 3 To 14
                If WS.Cells(c.Row, i) = "x" Then
                    Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
                End If
            Next

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .To = c.Offset(, 0)
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Daily Operational Safety Briefing"
                .Body = Msg
                .Attachments.Add MyFileCopy, 1
                .Send
            End With


        End If

    Next c

    MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

Abort:

    Application.Quit 'This will kill the Excel application, is this really what you want?


End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a permission denied error on `FileCopy MyFile, MyFileCopy` and here is what I have that line set to `MyFileCopy = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Attachment.xlsm"`.  Thank you :).  I have the abort code in there to close the application as hopefully this will help.

Comment: Is the `MyFile` workbook open? If so, you won't be able to copy it.

Comment: Yes it is, the button is in sheet1 and the `MyFile` is sheet2.  I am trying to avoid having the user update the file in one location then goto another to run the VB. Thank you :).  Can the copy be saved elsewhere and then that is used as the attachment?  Thank you :).

Comment: Well, that my friend, changes the game significantly. See my updated code.

Comment: I get a runtime error 1004 on the `.SaveAs MyFileCopy`.  I'm not sure how to change it so the macro will still run.  Thank you :).

Comment: strange. works for me. Is `MyFileCopy` a valid path on your network?

Comment: I am thinking it is not as I am getting an invalid outside procedure with the `MyFileCopy` line.  I updated the code as well to show exactly what I have. Thank you very much :).

Comment: you need to make sure that the string you put into `MyFileCopy` is valid. Once that is correct, the line should work. Unless, there is something I cannot see at the moment.

Comment: I think the issue is that the `MyFileCopy` attachment is not being saved in the directory.The portion up to the DOSE reporting attachment is valid `L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Attachment.xlsm`.  That attachment only needs to be saved until it is emailed then it can be deleted.  Is that the issue?  Thank you :).

Comment: what happens if you manually copy sheet2 out of the main workbook and save it to the directory with the location and name in `MyFileCopy`?

Comment: I changed the `MyFileCopy` to xlsx and it worked.  Is there a way to remove the new file when the email is sent and the attachment is sent currently, when either C2 or D2 is marked with an "x".  Can it only be sent if D2 has an "x".  Thank you :).

Comment: use a Kill statement `Kill MyFileCopy` when you want to delete. With the code you have, I think you can very easily modify the C2 or D2 marked with an X thing. If you can't, please post another question. Also, mark this as solved, because it is. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help :).